# script to use Left Click as Left Shift does not work correctly

Tags: autohotkey

I've search AHK forums but couldn't solution.

The script I found on AHK to use LShift as LButton does not work correctly..when press & hold left shift and move the mouse pointer, it can't copy text exactly like as if click and hold left mouse. What I mean by exactly is.. press & hold left shift and move the mouse pointer copies the whole paragraph or section of text..not just the few words I wanted.

My first time here & newbie w/ AHK. Your time is appreciated.

```
~Lshift::  
Send {LButton}  
return  
F10::exitapp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
~Lshift::  
Send {LButton Down} ; Press the LButton key Down
KeyWait, LShift ; Wait for the LShift key to be lifted
Send {LButton Up} ; Release the LButton key
return

F10::exitapp
```