# How to note consume the key being pressed when it has a prefix key?

Tags: autohotkey, prefix

I have this hotkey

```
~LShift & LButton::(.....)
```

The ~ is supposed to allow the hotkey from being blocked, but it seems that it is not allowing the Mouse Left click through.

I tried the following with no success:

```
~LShift & ~LButton::(.....)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like the second example I gave is what is correct. But my confusion is coming from Send (keys) is reset the shift key... Hmm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [script to use Left Click as Left Shift does not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722671/script-to-use-left-click-as-left-shift-does-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an application specific issue.
The first bit is working as intended.